# Theano based libraries for RNN based speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, theano, lstm

Um trying to do speech recognition using RNN. It would be really helpful if i could get some suggestions on best theano based libraries that I can use for RNN based speech recognition. (I am hoping to use CTC Connectionist Temporal Classification as well)

Comment: Sadly, off topic for StackOverflow, maybe try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, is that so. Thanks for the link, i posted my question there... :)

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/theano-based-libraries-for-rnn-based-speech-recognition/27013#27013